# Space counting wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im reading a text files that identifies specific characteristics in the text. Everything turns out fine until it reaches the spaces part where it displays that there are 15 spaces instead of 6.

The text file is

```
Hello
Do school units regularly
Attend seminars
Study 4 tests
Bye
```

and the script is

```
def main():
    lower_case = 0
    upper_case = 0
    numbers = 0
    whitespace = 0
    with open("text.txt", "r") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            lower_case += sum(1 for x in line if x.islower())
            upper_case += sum(1 for x in line if x.isupper())
            numbers += sum(1 for x in line if x.isdigit())
            whitespace += sum(1 for x in line if x.isspace())

    print 'Lower case Letters: %s' % lower_case
    print 'Upper case Letters: %s' % upper_case
    print 'Numbers: %s' % numbers
    print 'Spaces: %s' % whitespace


main()
```

Is there anything that should be changed so the number of spaces will turn up as 6?

Comment: Add a `print repr(line)` inside the loop and you'll see what all the characters are. There's probably extra newline characters at the end. You can remove them with `line.rstrip()` or `if line.endswith('\n'): line = line[:-1]`.

Comment: Also in python `True == 1` and `False == 0` so you can add them, i.e. `lower_case += sum(x.islower() for x in line)` or even `sum(map(str.islower, line))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because line breaks are also considered to be spaces. Now, the file you are opening was probably created on Windows, and on Windows a line break is two characters (the actual line break, and a caret return). Since you have five lines, you get extra 10 whitespaces, totalling 16 (one gets lost somewhere, I can only guess that one of the lines has a different line break at the end, which lacks a caret return).

To fix it, just strip the line when you count whitespaces.

```
whitespace += sum(1 for x in line.strip() if x.isspace())
```

This will, however, also strip out any trailing and leading spaces which are not line breaks. To only strip out linebreaks from the end, you can do

```
whitespace += sum(1 for x in line.rstrip("\r\n") if x.isspace())
```

Comment: On Windows, those CRLF line endings would be translated to plain LFs, because the file is opened in text mode. It might be a file created on Windows and opened on Unix.

Comment: `line.rstrip('\r\n')` will do what you suggested at the end.

Comment: I would guess that the last line has neither CR nor LF. It *does* have a trailing space, though.

Comment: @user2357112, good point, I though about it, but didn't remember if "r" opens in text or binary mode, and guessed it was binary. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to not use `isspace()` but rather check for the characters you want, e.g.

```
whitespace += line.count(' ') + line.count('\t')
```